# I want to display a dataframe in jupyter notebook which is updating frequently in micro seconds

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter

when I am using `clear_output()`, it is blinking. I want to display it constantly with frequently changing values, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
clear_output(wait=True)
```

which waits until the new output is available for rendering

Answer (score -1):

Try To Add Wait

Try This:

```
clear_output(wait=True)
```

it waits until the new output is available for rendering